# Do I resolve non-Shadow "Revealed" effects when revealing a Shadow card?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

When I reveal a Shadow card during the Combat phase, do I also resolve any non-shadow Revealed effects on that card?  For example, if an enemy reveals The Necromancer's Reach as a Shadow card, do I also deal 1 damage to each exhausted character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 3 of the Combat phase in the rulebook:

> 3. Resolve shadow effect. The active player flips that enemy’s shadow card faceup and resolves any shadow effect that card might have.

You only use the shadow part of the card when resolving shadow cards. When you flip a card like The Necromancer's Reach where there is no shadow effect, you are in luck.